# IIS disable ocsp stapling using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, iis

There is checkbox "Disable OCSP stapling" in IIS GUI,
how do i disable same in powershell?

Have tried : webadministration module Set-WebConfiguration
and netsh http update sslcert
but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the OCSP stapling is disabled by default, because of potential performance issues.

If you want to disbale it, I suggest you could run below command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\" -Name "EnableOcspStaplingForSni" -PropertyType DWord -Value 0
```

Comment: I just tried that , and restarted site, Edge browser still tries to check certificate. (reaches timeout and then continues to site) Only if i disable OCSP in Internet Options of Client it will not check certificate. Which is strange because when i configured site with GUI , browser didn't tried to check certificate.

Comment: Ok nevermind, i got it. There was no server binding to response on http port 80 , so Edge goes trough timeout.